# Cant copy a png image in c#

Tags: c#

I am creating an app that i need to copy some png files.

I already have  searching with many keywords, finding many solutions and none of them worked, so i decided to ask here.

There is the code,it uses a windows forms and "this" refers to this window

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //yes i commented them to solve why the file was not copying
            //try
            {
                FileInfo x = new FileInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\some_location");
                x.CopyTo(textBox1.Text);
            }
            //catch
            { }
            this.Close();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openDialog.Title = "Select Image To Load";
            openDialog.Filter = "Text Files (*.png)|*.png" + "|" + "All Files (*.*)|*.*";

            if (openDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string PathData = openDialog.FileName;
                textBox1.Text = PathData;

            }
        }
```

I have gotten several different errors, but most common there is:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException
```

Comment: Because you don't have access to source and/or target.  You are sure all path are good and you have access to them?

Comment: all paths are fine, but even desktop folder give same error. So is there a path to use?

Comment: Surely the path is chosen by the user? But what DanB said; you don't have access to either the source path or the dest path. Try something simpler, like c:\temp to c:\temp2, and make a call to `Directory.CreateDirectory(@"c:\temp2")` before you copy there. Also, in future when posting code that throws an exception, say which line causes the exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks a bit weird to me that you're using an `OpenFileDialog` to select a *destination*. I'd assume you'd want to either do it the other way around:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //yes i commented them to solve why the file was not copying
        //try
        {
            FileInfo x = new FileInfo(textBox1.Text);
            x.CopyTo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\some_location");
        }
        //catch
        { }
        this.Close();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openDialog.Title = "Select Image To Load";
        openDialog.Filter = "Text Files (*.png)|*.png" + "|" + "All Files (*.*)|*.*";

        if (openDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string PathData = openDialog.FileName;
            textBox1.Text = PathData;

        }
    }
```

or use [SaveFileDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog?view=netframework-4.8) instead.